# How do I use VST.Net to load one plugin and use it with multi connection

Tags: c#, naudio, vst, naudio-framework

I had a vstplugin to remove noise of sound.
I made connection it with input device and output device and it worked fine.
Load vst function

```
public static void LoadPlugin(string path, out VstPluginContext plugin)
    {
        var hcs = new HostCommandStub();
        hcs.PluginCalled += new EventHandler<PluginCalledEventArgs>(HostCmdStub_PluginCalled);
        try
        {
            plugin = VstPluginContext.Create(path, hcs);
            plugin.Set("PluginPath", path);
            plugin.Set("HotCmdStub", hcs);

            plugin.PluginCommandStub.Commands.Open();
            plugin.PluginCommandStub.Commands.MainsChanged(true);
            _logger.Info("Load VST Plugin successful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            plugin = null;
            _logger.Error("Failed to load VST Plugin", ex);
        }
    }
```

Create connection:

```
public static void ConnectPlugin(bool restartDevice = false, bool byPass = false, bool debug = false)
    {
        _IsConnecting = true;
        try
        {
            _currentConfig = new CurrentConfig
            {
                InputDeviceNum = _currentInput?.DeviceNumber ?? 0,
                OutputDeviceNum = _currentOutput?.DeviceNumber ?? 1,
                ByPass = byPass,
                Debug = debug
            };

            if (!restartDevice && waveIn != null) return;

            DisconnectDevices();

            if (_currentInput == null || _currentOutput == null) return;

            sampleRate = 48000f;
            blockSize = (int)(4800);

            waveIn = new WaveInEvent();
            waveIn.BufferMilliseconds = 100;
            waveIn.DataAvailable += Plugin_DataAvailable;
            waveIn.DeviceNumber = _currentConfig.InputDeviceNum;
            waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat((int)sampleRate, 16, 1);

            waveProviderout = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat) { DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true };

            int inputCount = _vstPlugin.PluginInfo.AudioInputCount;
            int outputCount = _vstPlugin.PluginInfo.AudioOutputCount;

            var inputMgr = new VstAudioBufferManager(inputCount, blockSize);
            var outputMgr = new VstAudioBufferManager(outputCount, blockSize);

            _vstPlugin.PluginCommandStub.Commands.SetBlockSize(blockSize);
            _vstPlugin.PluginCommandStub.Commands.SetSampleRate(sampleRate);
            _vstPlugin.PluginCommandStub.Commands.SetProcessPrecision(VstProcessPrecision.Process32);

            // set value for bypass
            _vstPlugin.PluginCommandStub.Commands.SetBypass(_currentConfig.ByPass);

            // set value for debug - index = 0
            _vstPlugin.PluginCommandStub.Commands.SetParameter(0, _currentConfig.Debug ? 1f : 0);

            inputBuffers = inputMgr.Buffers.ToArray();
            outputBuffers = outputMgr.Buffers.ToArray();

            waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
            waveOut.DesiredLatency = 100;
            waveOut.DeviceNumber = _currentConfig?.OutputDeviceNum ?? 1;
            waveOut.Init(waveProviderout);

            waveOut.Play();

            waveIn.StartRecording();

            //SetScheduleForReset(1800000); // reset plugin every 2 hours (7200000 ms)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        _IsConnecting = false;

        Autofix();
    }
```

Currently I want to add a connection from a new input device to a new output device with the same plugin but with a different bypass parameter.. I tried to clone the above code to create a new connection, it works fine, but it doesn't seem to receive the bypass parameter. Please help me

- 1 vst plugin (noise removed)
- Connections

  - Connection 1: Input Device A ---> Output Device B: with bypass = false
  - Connection 2: Input Device C ---> Output Device D: with bypass = true

Thanks

Comment: Why not make two instances of the same plugin (call LoadPlugin again) and hook them up to the different inputs/outputs? You cannot have one plugin (instance) with different values for any properties or parameters (bypass) [2c]

Comment: Thanks @obiwanjacobi, Today I encountered a problem loading the plugin.
`System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at Jacobi.Vst.Host.Interop.VstUnmanagedPluginContext.Initialize(String pluginPath)
   at Jacobi.Vst.Host.Interop.VstPluginContext.Create(String pluginPath, IVstHostCommandStub hostCmdStub)`
Before that, it worked fine. I don't know why

Comment: I don't think VST.NET does any division - so its probably the plugin you try to load?
https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vst.net/blob/22f2d25184ad1b5dc3396af93058646c2e01f503/Source/Code/Jacobi.Vst.Interop/Host/VstUnmanagedPluginContext.cpp#L59
Perhaps clear any settings files (if any) for that plugin?

Comment: Currently, I call to load plugin twice for two connection, The first invoke: load successful, The second invoke failed after that.. When I turn off internet, It is loaded successful all the time. Is it because my plugin has any problem ?

Comment: Does that plugin behave the same way if you load it into another host/DAW?